# Unwanted blank page while making title

Tags: titles, geometry, setspace

I decided to change the geometry of my thesis as I realized the size difference between a4 paper and letter paper. When I change from a4 paper to letter page latex started producing an annoying blank page before my title. How can I get rid of it? My MWE is

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,width=180mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}

\def\Unam{Universidad Nacional Aut\'{o}noma de M\'{e}xico}
\def\Ier{Instituto de Energ\'{i}as Renovables}
\def\Ii{Instituto de Ingenier\'{i}a}
\def\Titulo{Topological impact of nano-electrodes on the structure of the electrical double layer and the differential capacitance}
\def\Yo{Adri\'{a}n Silva Caballero}
\def\Marcelo{Dr. Marcelo Lozada y Cassou}
\def\Lugar{Temixco, Mor.}
\def\fecha{12 de marzo de 2020}
\def\fechaingles{March 12, 2020}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
        \begin{titlepage}
        % Left layout - Logos
        \begin{minipage}[c][257mm][s]{25mm}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=26mm]{Escudo-UNAM}\\[10pt]
            \hskip 2pt\vrule width 2pt height 187mm
            \hskip 1mm\vrule width 1pt height 187mm\\[10pt]
            \includegraphics[height=18mm]{logo-ierii}
        \end{minipage}\hskip 10pt
        % Right layout - Titles
        \begin{minipage}[c][257mm][s]{135mm}
            \centering
            % University, institute, department and title
            \vspace{4.5mm}
            \resizebox{,99\columnwidth}{!}{{\Large\scshape \Unam}}
            \vspace{3mm}\hrule height 2pt
            \vspace{1mm}\hrule height 1pt
            \vspace{3.5mm}
            {\large\scshape \Ier\\[1pt]\Ii}\\[3pt]
            % Title
            \vspace{25mm}
            {\begin{singlespace}\Large{\textbf{\scshape\Titulo}}\end{singlespace}}
            \vspace{27mm}
            % Degree, author, supervisor and date
            {\Large \textbf{T E S I S}}\\[3pt]
            \small QUE PARA OBTENER EL TÍTULO DE\\[8pt]
            {\large\scshape Ingeniero en Energías Renovables}

            \vspace{22mm}
            \textbf{P R E S E N T A}\\[4pt]
            {\large\scshape \Yo}

            \vspace{22mm}
            {\small\bf DIRECTOR DE TESIS}\\[2pt]
            {\scshape \Marcelo}

            \vspace{38mm}
            {\scshape {\relax}{\hfill}{\Lugar, a \fecha}}

        \end{minipage}
        \newpage
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \centering\large
        {\setstretch{1.2}\Large\bfseries \Titulo}\\[15pt]
        by\\[15pt]
        {\Large \Yo}
        \\[30pt]
        Thesis presented to obtain the title of
        \\[5pt]
        Engineer in Renewable Energies
        \\[10pt]
        in the
        \\[15pt]
        {{\scshape \Ier}}\\[20pt]
        {\Large\scshape\Unam}
        \\[25pt]
        \Lugar.\, \fechaingles
        \vspace*{\fill}     
    \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The contents of your title page are vertically too large for a letterpaper sized paper. (For a visual guideline add `showframe` to the `geometry` options.) To overcome this issue, reduce the vertical spaces between the entries in your titlepage environment.

Comment: Reduce the height of your title page.

Comment: You are specifying letterpaper but all lengths in mm?  that's perfectly legal but somewhat unusual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log file should show something like

```latex
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1]
Overfull \vbox (46.20601pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[2{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
```

What does this mean? That LaTeX has found an object too big in the first page, so it is forced to eject an almost empty page (there is always something invisible in the first page, followed by a feasible page break point) which produces the `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000)` message.

Next TeX tries to fit the object in the next page, but it can't, so it issues an `Overfull \vbox` message and moves on (there is no feasible page break point in the title page).

Obviously the problem is in the vertical size of the `minipage`s, which is set to 257mm that is too much for Letter paper that's less tall than A4 paper.

The overfull is 46.2pt, which corresponds to 16.24mm.

If I change 257mm to 240mm, the blank page disappears.